# Where is the best place in your folder structure to place angular services?

Tags: angular

I am debating between having a central core library for storing all services and models or keep them inside the modules used for the app logic? What do people generally do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [**`Angular style guide`**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide),

> Consider not providing services in shared modules. Services are
>   usually singletons that are provided once for the entire application
>   or in a particular feature module. There are exceptions, however. For
>   example, in the sample code that follows, notice that the SharedModule
>   provides FilterTextService. This is acceptable here because the
>   service is stateless;that is, the consumers of the service aren't
>   impacted by new instances.

Here is a [sample architecture structure](https://github.com/sajeetharan/Angular-Structure) that you could follow,

[image]

Comment: Thx so for example api calls to server best to put those in a service in each feature module along with related interface/model definition as opposed to shared module?

Comment: whatever the core features should go to core module and feature related ones can resides within the feature modules

Comment: Thx the question is you could for feature have some logic per feature service api calls and spread it across each feature or you could consolidate all of those related methods into one service and drop into core, just not sure which to follow

Comment: i think you need to structure in a way that you abstract the operations (put,get,post etc) to a service handler and put that in core module and make other services to each feature module

Comment: Does it make sense to have full models or just simple interfaces for your json responses ?